# create a new map with a jquery function

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

i'm using google maps v3 and i want create a new map associate to a event with a combo but i don't know why don't work, take a look to my code.

**Note** i debug the code and works great the problem it's that the map doesn't show

```
$(document).ready(initialize);

var map;

function initialize() {

x = $(".comboMap");
x.change(buildMap);
}

function buildMap(){
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "SaveIndicators.aspx/findMapParameters",
    data: "{idMapa: '" + $(".comboMap").val() + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: response
});
}

/***Sets the values in the map****/
function response(values) {

var location = values.d.split(",");
var lat = parseFloat(location[0]);
var lng = parseFloat(location[1]);
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
var mapDiv = $("#map-canvas")[0];
map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: latLng,
    zoom: location[2],
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: true
});

}
```

Comment: How is the height of the map div determined? It might be `0`, which is a problem for Google Maps.

Comment: @Matt Ball hi and thanks for asking it's a div with height and width

Comment: What is the HTML that this script is acting on?

Comment: (Specifically, is the id of the div really "map-canvas" like you have in your code here, or is it "map_canvas" which is what Google uses in their samples?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your string value for the zoom level to an integer:

```
function response(values) {

    var location = values.d.split(",");
    var lat = parseFloat(location[0]);
    var lng = parseFloat(location[1]);
    var zoom = parseInt(location[2]);
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var mapDiv = $("#map_canvas")[0];
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: zoom,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: true
    });
}
```

I would have thought it would have cast the value passing the string, but it didn't.  I had to use parseInt() to make an integer to get the Map constructor to treat it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

have you included a reference to google maps script in the header of your page?

are you getting any javascript errors when the page loads?

are you sure your service call is returning data and in the correct format?  it may be returning XML instead of JSON.

**EDIT:**

i notice you are doing var mapDiv = $("#map-canvas")[0];  what is the reason for treating it like an array?  you are asking for it by name, so there should only be one on the page anyway....

Comment: Thanks for asking, yes the script it's registred and it's not a problem about returning data

Comment: have updated my answer with another question for you...  pasting the aspx code may help too...

Comment: that's for manner of treating the object's in jquery and the form the google maps expects the object. if you don't use jquery the equivalent of '$("#map-canvas")[0]' it's 'document.getElementById('map-canvas')'